# Azure Service Fabric and Microservices Architecture

Tags: azure, architecture, microservices, azure-service-fabric

Imagine following scenario:

We build an IoT solution and use Azure Service Fabric to implement the complete backend.

Messages from devices flow through the IoT Hub to the **Device Actor** which processes those messages.

We also have a web API as a **stateless service** through which people can put some data (using an SPA) in a database.

Now the Device Actor needs this data to make some decisions.
In terms of Microservices architecture Device Actor could use that stateless service to retrieve the data (avoiding integration through the database). But if we consider that the Device Actor scales to many thousands devices that stateless service would be the bottleneck unless we scale it too (only because of devices).

So my question is: what is the best approach here?

Comment: Will your database be able to process such amount of requests? If no, then, as for me, scaling Stateless Service is more simpler task than scaling database.

Comment: This has also occurred to me. In case of Azure Table Storage I think it could handle the load given a good partitioning schema

Comment: Q: Is the collected data immutable once entered, or subject to updates? It's most cases trivial to implement output model caching on the API layer, and it scales well.

Comment: No the data is not immutable but still good point regarding caching. Another idea would be to cache the data in the local state of the Actor (StateManager) the API could notify the specific Actor instance about data change and the Actor could update its state, what do u think guys?

Comment: What you will do if after such call actor won't be able to process the request? As I understood, you will not wait the end of processing on API level, you want to return 200 response to the devices immediately and asynchronously call actor to update its state and do some work. Is it right? Or will you wait?

Comment: Maybe I did not describe my case well enough so let me make it more concrete: user can subscribe to notifications for error events from devices through the web app. the device actor needs this subscription information in order to trigger the notification.So the whole question is about the best approach to get this data into the actor.

Comment: Interesting. So it sounds like you have a classic pub sub case. (n) devices are pump messages. (n) subscribers for notifications where the criteria is subclassess of messages (errors). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes devices pump messages and users create subscriptions to subclasses of messages (error). The Actor needs the subscription info to publish notifications (email). It is sort of pub sub and one could easily implement it using e.g. Service Bus topics. I am unsure whether it is a good option to combine Service Bus with Service Fabric though. I am not aware of any pub sub mechanism in Service Fabric other than actor events which are not applicable here

Comment: It is not bad to combine Service Bus with Service Fabric, but you can look at Event Hubs as well. How many users subscribed to notifications do you expect? What kind of notifications — PUSH or something else? How large the notification information? How many subscribes could have one device?